# Did life evolve in Star Wars, or was it created by the Force?

Tags: star-wars, the-force, biology, evolution

I was wondering how exactly life originated in the Star Wars universe. Did life arise through natural processes (eg. Darwinian evolution) like on earth, or did the Force somehow "create" life? Did something like theistic evolution happen where the Force guided the process? Did the Force have anything to do with the origin of life in Star Wars?

Comment: Legends or Canon?

Comment: "Where art thou, Darwin?"

Comment: These are some great questions, but one of the main philosophies of this site is AFAIK *"one question - one answer"*; it means that you must ask a question that has a precise and objective answer. Try to edit your question to make it more precise, as per [help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I would prefer canon, unless this has only been established through legends.

Comment: I disagree, @Gallifreian, he *is* asking one question, he's just asking it a few different ways to make sure he covers his bases.

Comment: great question, I've been looking into that myself and didn't find a satisfactory answer myself. The only thing we know for sure is that humans come from Coruscant and have been spreading through the galaxy for a long time with different means of transport.

Answer (score 1):

The Force did not create life. In fact, life created the Force, so it would be impossible for the Force to have created life. (See clip- "It's an energy field created by all living things.") It is always possible that life, after creating the Force, was influenced by the Force, and so was shaped by its own creation, but life came first.

Most likely, life in the Star Wars universe actually arose several times. It seems unlikely that one form of life touched down on all the planets in the universe, then left each one alone to evolve in peace for millennia. It is much more probable that life evolved separately on each planet, eventually reaching out and contacting the other planets nearby, forming the interplanetary alliances and rivalries that we see in Star Wars. If this is the case, it is entirely possible that all of the different species in the universe run on different code, use different proteins, and may not even be "alive" as we humans think of it. A good follow-up question would be, "Do the creatures of Star Wars share DNA, or run on it at all?" Unfortunately, only George Lucas will actually have an answer, and even he might not have thought that far.

Answer (score 1):

Life came into being well before The Force showed up. Obi-Wan made it clear that it was *created by living beings*. Having The Force being around before life does seems a little weird.

Comment: This adds nothing that is not already in the accepted answer.